# openSettings plugin cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, settings

I installed the plugin [OpenSettings](https://github.com/erikhuisman/cordova-plugin-opensettings) via `node.js` with this command in my project:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/erikhuisman/cordova-plugin-opensettings.git
```

But when I use method `OpenSettings.setting()` logcat return me an error:

> OpenSettings.settings error at
>   file:///android_asset/www/plugins/nl.tapme.cordova.opensettings/www/OpenSettings.js:23

This is `OpenSettings.js`:

```
cordova.define("nl.tapme.cordova.opensettings.OpenSettings", function(require, exports, module) { module.exports = OpenSettings = {};

OpenSettings.settings = function(app, callback) {
    cordova.exec(
        // Success callback
        callback,
        // Failure callback
        function(err) { console.log('OpenSettins.settings error'); },
        // Native Class Name
        "OpenSettings",
        // Name of method in native class.
        "settings",
        // array of args to pass to method.
        []
    );
};

OpenSettings.bluetooth = function (app, callback) {
    cordova.exec(
        // Success callback
        callback,
        // Failure callback
        function(err) { console.log('OpenSettings.bluetooth error'); },
        // Native Class Name
        "OpenSettings",
        // Name of method in native class.
        "bluetooth",
        // array of args to pass to method.
        []
    );
};

OpenSettings.bluetoothStatus = function (app, callback) {
    cordova.exec(
        // Success callback
        callback,
        // Failure callback
        function(err) { console.log('OpenSettins.bluetoothStatus error'); },
        // Native Class Name
        "OpenSettings",
        // Name of method in native class.
        "bluetoothStatus",
        // array of args to pass to method.
        []
    );
};

OpenSettings.bluetoothChange = function (callback) {
    cordova.exec(
        // Success callback
        callback,
        // Failure callback
        function(err) { console.log('OpenSettins.bluetoothChange error'); },
        // Native Class Name
        "OpenSettings",
        // Name of method in native class.
        "bluetoothChange",
        // array of args to pass to method.
        []
    );
};

return OpenSettings;

});
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to test this plugin -> https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings the first one you posted already did not work for me too.

Install it like this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings.git
```

and use it like this:

```
cordova.plugins.settings.open(settingsSuccess,settingsFail);
```

---

**Full snippet**:

```
function settingsSuccess() {
    console.log('settings opened');
}

function settingsFail() {
    console.log('open settings failed');
}

function openSettingsNow() {
    cordova.plugins.settings.open(settingsSuccess,settingsFail);
}
```

---

The plugin will open this overview: [image]

Comment: I have only to copy and paste cordova.plugins.settings.open(success_callback,failure_callback) where I need open settings ?

Comment: Because now logcat return me " success_callback is not defined"

Comment: You're new to development, aren't you? I'm going to edit my answer. Just a sec.

Comment: You than bind `openSettingsNow` to your button or link or anything like that.

Comment: Than please accept my answer and vote it up :) i just upvoted your question - this is how it works here.

Comment: Now it open the location settings... There is a way to open general settings?

Comment: The plugin will ever open the settings for that application so it'll show you an overview of the permissions you granted or you didn't grant. You can than choose to allow them there or to disallow them.

Comment: There is a way to send usere in different setting? In my app there is a part that check if gps is enable (if it's disable send user to location setting), and a part that check if internet connection is enable. I would like that, if internet is disable, user will send to network setting. How can I modify code to do that?  I use Android

Comment: Nope, there is no way of doing this. But that are problems, which the user has to handle in my mind. You can open the settings, directly at that part, where the user can enable or disable camera settings, location settings etc. etc. but changing from airplane to normal mode or activating disables network is a choice which the user has to make. In activated airplane mode by using functions which need internet, the device will automatically ask you to disable or enable it. Nothing to do for you - **in my mind**

Comment: Try this new plugin, with a better support for iOS: https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings